# Apache Camel : Restlet request error

Tags: spring, maven, servlets, apache-camel, restlet

So I'm currently working with Camel and right now I would like to try to create a webapp with camel and restlet, so I tried this tutorial

https://camel.apache.org/restlet.html

But right now isn't really working. I'm having this error in my Tomcat log.

```
    INFO: La servlet RestletServlet est marquÈ comme indisponible
25 avr. 2014 14:21:01 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'allocation pour la servlet RestletServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>restlet</groupId>
<artifactId>restlet</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>restlet</name>

<properties>
    <customer>control</customer>
    <camelversion>2.11.1</camelversion>
    <restlet-version>2.0.15</restlet-version>
    <spring-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <maven-jetty-plugin-version>6.1.25</maven-jetty-plugin-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- camel -->
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camelversion}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camelversion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-exec</artifactId>
        <version>${camelversion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${camelversion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${camelversion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
        <version>${camelversion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
        <version>${camelversion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
        <version>${restlet-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${camelversion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <directory>build</directory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jetty-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>${basedir}/target/camel-restlet.war</webApp>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>    
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>  
        <id>maven-restlet</id>  
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>  
        <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>  
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

this is my web.xml

```
<!-- Restlet Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.component</param-name>
        <param-value>RestletComponent</param-value>
    </init-param>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my *context*

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="RS_RestletDemo">
        <from uri="restlet:/demo/{id}" />
        <transform>
<simple>Request type : ${header.CamelHttpMethod} and ID :${header.id}</simple>
        </transform>
    </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="RestletComponent" class="org.restlet.Component" />

<bean id="RestletComponentService"      class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="RestletComponent" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
 </beans>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something...

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Check your .war file to see if you have multiple versions of Spring under WEB-INF/lib. If you do, make sure to have .jars of only one version.

Answer (score 0):

Camel 2.11.1 is using Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE, and your pom spring version is 3.2.3.RELEASE so you need to updated you pom spring version to 3.1.4.RELEASE, or use exclusions to fix the spring version miss match.

BTW, you can use mvn dependency:tree to find out that spring version miss match.